# Character recognition model possibly overfitting?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm trying to train a model to recognize gestures drawn using a wand which is picked up by an IR camera and fed into a model.
I trained the model using an A-Z handwritten character dataset, as well as two additional custom symbols that I have trained.
Currently it detects all the symbols correctly when drawing them directly, but if any random symbols/drawings are put into the model it will also identify them as being one of the two custom symbols I've added.
This is my confusion matrix:
[image]

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, since your model has to classify any given input into any one class, your model seems to be trying to classify the random inputs to your custom classes. It would be useful if you could provide more information about your custom classes.

I guess you could try introducing a component of confidence in your class predictions, i.e. assuming you're using softmax, for any input, you can only truly accept a classification if the probability given for a class is above a certain threshold, else classify as random.

Additionally, you could try adding another custom class and train your model with all the random symbols but I don't think it is ideal.